# Using a random picture instead of a specific picture?

Tags: php, email, random

my current script is this:

```
$attach[] = array('pics/pic1.jpg', 'image/jpeg');
```

how can i change it, so it pics a random picture in the pics/ folder instead of a specified?

Theres like 20 pics in pics/

I want the script uses a random.

Comment: Are the pics numbered from `pic1.jpg` to `pic20.jpg`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`array_rand()`](http://www.php.net/array_rand) for this. If you don't already have all files in an array, you can easily do it with [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/glob)

```
$all_pics = array();
foreach (glob("./pics/*") as $filename)
    $all_pics[] = array($filename, filetype($filename));

$random_pic = array_rand($all_pics);
```

This is universal, if you are sure your pictures are all named `pic1`, `pic2`, etc., it is probably better to just generate a random number and use it as in [sal00ms answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19838412/1557526).

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:

```
$attach[] = array('pics/pic'.rand(1,20).'.jpg', 'image/jpeg');
```

And rename your files pic1,pic2...,pic20

Answer (score 0):

You may also try something like this

```
function getRandomImage()
{
    // add more images in the array
    $pics = array('pics/pic1.jpg', 'image/pic.jpeg', 'photo/pic.png');
    $i = rand(0, count($pics)-1);
    return $pics[$i];
}

$image = getRandomImage();
```

Answer (score 0):

First generate a random number!

```
 $random_number = rand(0, 19);
```

Then, get all the pics of the folder in an array.

```
 $pics = glob("pics/*");
```

Then, get the random pic from the array using random number

```
 $random_pic = $pics[$random_number];
```

You can simplify it in one step as

```
 $random_pic = glob("pics/*")[rand(0, 19)];
```